# Rails Server keeps exiting on "rails server" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here are my specs: Ruby 2.4.0, Rails 5.1.3, postgres 9.6, windows 10 running rails with Bash Ubuntu.  Whenever I try running rails server it exits me, I'm at the root of the project.  It wasn't happening before. Here are the gems I recently installed: boostrap-sass, devise, toastr-rails, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

```
 rails server
 => Booting Puma
 => Rails 5.1.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
 => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
 Exiting
 /home/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:228:in `mkdir': File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /mnt/c/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/xxxxx/tmp/pids (Errno::EEXIST)

 from /home/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:228:in `fu_mkdir'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:204:in `reverse_each'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:204:in `block in mkdir_p'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:190:in `each'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/fileutils.rb:190:in `mkdir_p'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:75:in `block in create_tmp_directories'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:74:in `each'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:74:in `create_tmp_directories'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:40:in `start'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:131:in `block in perform'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `tap'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `perform'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'

 from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'

 from bin/rails:4:in `require'
 from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the folder or file `/mnt/c/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/xxxxx/tmp/pids` and try again?

Comment: It failed because it was trying to make a folder where the file was. It could not create the folder until the file was deleted.

Comment: I stopped the server and it keeps doing it.  I have to keep deleting it to restart it.

Comment: Something is misconfigured. It should not need to delete a file every time you start the server.